# Python: comparing items in lists with for-loop

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, comparison

I am trying to compare bunch of pair of lists and see if there is any same item in both lists with loops, but it looks like it's missing one item everytime I run it.

```
for item in alp: 
   for item2 in numbers: 
      if type((pos_ans[str(item) + str(item2)])) != int: 
         for item3 in (pos_ans[str(item) + str(item2)]): 
            if item3 in listing[item + "l"]: 
               (pos_ans[str(item) + str(item2)]).remove(item3)
```

`pos_ans[str(item) + str(item2)]` is one list, and `listing[item + "l"]` is another list. 
It usually works fine, but misses one or two items sometimes.

Comment: Could you add example input that specifically fails?

Comment: When (pos_ans[str(item) + str(item2)]) would be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and listing[item + "l"] would be [1,2,3,4,6,7], the result of pos_ans[str(item) + str(item2)] would come out as [2,4,5,7,8,9], having 2,4, and 7 not removed. It's probably because whenever it removes the item from the list the list gets shorter and the next item wouldn't necessarily be the item that was next to the removed item (I mean, it skips one). Is there any other way to do the same thing in a simple but the right way? I'm still new to python, and I can't think right now :(          @jsalonen

Comment: @Dennis: The simplest way would be not to remove items, but to create another list that will gather results if they are not treated as the ones that should be removed. But I am not sure what your code does, maybe try to simplify it so it shows only the issue you have problems with?

Comment: @Tadeck: so alp is a list of alphabets from A to I, numbers is a list of numbers from 1 to 9, pos_ans is a dictionary with keys from A1 to I9 with values of lists containing certain numbers, and listing[item + "l"] is another dictionary containing keys with certain numbers. Unless the pos_ans is not an integer (and is a list), it should have a list containing all the numbers from 1 to 9 for the first time, and I'm trying to remove certain numbers from the values of listing[item + "l"] from the pos_ans for each key.

Comment: Since I already have a lot of lists that I have to handle, I didn't want to create more lists, because I thought that would make me confused.. but if there isn't any other simple solutions that I would probably have to do it.

Comment: @Dennis: Ok, I see that this may be simplified a lot. For example you can `alp` usage in loop with `for letter_ord in xrange(65, 74)` (where `letter_ord` can be changed into letter by `letter = chr(letter_ord)`. You can also change `for item2 in numbers` into `for item2 in xrange(1,10)`. That way you get rid of two lists.

Comment: @Dennis: Here is an example on how it works: [codepad.org/aANGPmgP](http://codepad.org/aANGPmgP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is difficult to tell exactly without more context, you might have better luck–if they really are the same object–putting the objects into [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)s and then calling `intersect` between them to see where the overlap is.

Comment: After I read your answer, I searched for sets and intersect a bit, but I'm not really sure how I'm supposed to implement those for my case. Whenever I try ~.intersect(~), it gives me an error for some reason. I think I'm missing something here. Could you give a little more explanation regarding the above case? Thank you!

Comment: @Dennis, try `set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).difference([1,2,3,4,6,7])`

Comment: @gnibbler Thanks for the comment, and yeah I just found out about the set operations and while I was trying it I found out that the library (that we use for our cs class) that I imported defined "set" as another function, so whenever I use set, it doesn't work :( Is there anyway to not import just the "set" part from that library or maybe import "set" again?

Comment: @Dennis, that sucks. The best would be not to use `from ... import *` and just import the identifiers you need. Otherwise `set = __builtins__.set` should restore the builtin for you

Comment: @gnibbler Yeah.. I guess I'll just have to do from ... import a, b, c, ... Thanks for the comments!

Comment: @gnibbler: you could also do `from ... import *` followed by `del set` to unshadow the `set` built-in.  (assuming `from ... import *` is warranted)

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code, I can only assume one of your `If` statements is making a list item not be counted. Mostly `if type((pos_ans[str(item) + str(item2)])) != int:`

Is it possible that two lists both have integers in the same place?